# Ошибка микроразметки "невозможно определить принадлежность данных полей

Tags: php, html, микроразметка

Доброго времени суток!

У меня в коде выдает ошибку **"Невозможно определить принадлежность данных полей. Возможны две причины: эти поля некорректно размещены, либо указан лишний атрибут itemprop"**.

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Контекстная реклама">
<meta itemprop="headline" content="Контекстная реклама">
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**эти поля некорректно размещены**

> Атрибут `itemprop` используется для добавления свойств словаря микроданных к элементу. Имя свойства определяется значением `itemprop`, а значение свойства определяется **содержимым** HTML-элемента, к примеру, текстом который располагается **внутри элемента**

Зачем использовать `itemprop` в `meta`, если `meta` не имеет содержимого?

**либо указан лишний атрибут itemprop**

> `content` - Этот атрибут содержит значение для `http-equiv` или `name` атрибута, в зависимости от контекста.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить ошибку**

Наверное:

```
<meta name="name" content="Контекстная реклама">
<meta name="headline" content="Контекстная реклама">
```

Comment: А так выдает ошибку "Микроразметка не обнаружена"

Comment: это чья микроразметка? яндекса?

Comment: видимо её не в meta надо размещать. в мета только опен граф размещается. https://netpeaksoftware.com/ru/blog/chto-takoe-mikrorazmetka-sayta-i-zachem-ona-nuzhna

Comment: Да, только яндекс выдает ошибку, в гугле все ок. https://clientlab.ru/ Вот ссылка на сайт. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Я плохо понимаю в коде, но нужно как-то исправить ошибку)

Comment: ну все правильно. в мета и не должно быть разметки Schema.org

Comment: эта разметка для элементов на странице, а не для заголовка сайта